# Correct way to override a System::Forms class using C++/CLI

Tags: windows, forms, c++-cli

I´m build a custom textbox that will allow the user to type just some chars in keyboard. I´m overriding `System::Forms::MaskedTextBox` as follows:

```
public ref class MyMaskedTextBox : System::Windows::Forms::MaskedTextBox
{
    public:
        MyMaskedTextBox();
        ~MyMaskedTextBox();

        void OnKeyPress(System::Windows::Forms::KeyPressEventArgs^ e) override;

};

void MyMaskedTextBox::OnKeyPress(System::Windows::Forms::KeyPressEventArgs^ e)
{
    if ((e->KeyChar >= 'A' && e->KeyChar <= 'Z') ||
        (e->KeyChar >= '0' && e->KeyChar <= '9') ||
        e->KeyChar == '*' ||
        e->KeyChar == '-' ||
        e->KeyChar == '/' ||
        e->KeyChar == '.' ||
        e->KeyChar == ' ' ||
        e->KeyChar == (char) System::Windows::Forms::Keys::Back ||
        e->KeyChar == (char) System::Windows::Forms::Keys::Delete)
    {
        e->Handled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        e->Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Altough my function is being called, my `MyMaskedTextBox` behaviour is strange, like not limiting the number of chars as defined on its `MaxLength`property, not removing text when typing delete, among others.

Is my inheritance wrong or should I call the base class after processing my logic ? If so, how can I call the base class ?

Comment: Maybe you should suscribe to the KeyPress event rather than override OnKeyPress?

Comment: I need override, as my class implements other methods used systemwide.

Comment: You are *replacing* the virtual method, thus breaking MaskedTextBox::OnKeyPress().  You must call __super::OnKeyPress() so it can do its job properly.

Comment: Thanks Hans. I think I got the idea: `__super::OnKeyPress()` should go only  when `e->Handled = false`, right ? In case of `e->Handled = true` (not supported key), the function may return from that point as nothing will be processed....

Comment: No.  Frankly this is too risky since the base method does a lot of work that's based on internal state.  Keep it safe and subscribe the KeyPress event instead.

Comment: Humm.. Strange... `e->Handled = true` is not being enough to stop processing the unwanted keys... When set and calling `__super::OnKeyPress(e)` later makes the key being processed and shown in the control....